# How to maintain a history array for storing already searched terms using angular?

Tags: angular

I am working on a project using angular where I need to store all the previously searched terms (for example mobile phones in my case) and show those terms in a dropdown as history, so that user can reopen details of any previously searched phone by clicking on it.

Please recommend how can I obtain this functionality or give reference of any article that can be of any help.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
searchHistory = [];

query = '';

search() {
  // do your search then store the result
  if (!this.searchHistory.some(q => q === this.query)) {
    this.searchHistory = [...this.searchHistory, this.query];
  }
}
```

and in the template

```
<select (change)="query = $event.target.value">
  <option *ngFor="let previousQuery of searchHistory">{{previousQuery}}</option>
</select>
```

StackBlitz demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ra7a3y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you need the array to persist across different pages then you could move the array into a service that is provided in the root.

Comment: but what if I want this History array to retain its values even if the page refreshes.

Comment: sessionStorage can be used to store information across page refreshes and localStorage can be used to store across browser sessions.